# sync all tables between 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

I need some information on how to synchronize all tables and views in sql server. What I wanted to do is basically I want all production server has the same tables and views structures as the staging server.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: How up to date does the data need to be? That's really the question. If it can be a day behind, you can just restore a backup to the stage server. If it needs to be up to the minute, you'll need to look at mirroring, transaction log shipping or maybe even avilability groups. It all depends on what you need. Can you give us more info?

Comment: Hi kris, i actually don't need the data... i just want to take the tables from staging database and update it directly to production db

Comment: So you just want the tables, views and store procedures but no data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).  The command-line SqlPackage utility can be scheduled to Extract and Publish schema.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx.  Some operations cannot be done automatically, such as refactoring a single table into two separate ones.  Those operations will require custom scripts for data migrations.

There is also a schema compare tool from RedGate, SQL Compare, that provides similar functionality.  They also provide an automation API product.